# Is there a concept of scope or nested contexts within EF Core DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's say my application's DbContest is scoped to the http request. The way I would do it normally is any method that needs to make changes, simply makes changes to objects loaded up via DbContext. Then at the end of the http request, I call `SaveChangesAsync` to ensure all changes in the change tracker are applied at once on a transaction.

However, what if in the middle of that I want to fire a separate save - maybe its an update to a cached value - I would like to fire that save without everything else in the change tracker coming along for the ride. Is there some way of creating a "sub-context" or nested context, or whatever the concept would be called that would allow me to do that?

Comment: In the case that transaction fails and needs to roll back would this "sub transaction" also need to be rolled back or would you want that to behave as if it was on a different thread?

Comment: I would want it to be its own transaction entirely, So I guess really I'm talking about cloning the context or the change tracker or something. The problem is that it seems to be devilishly hard to use asp.net core DI to register the same type as both Scoped in most cases but transient in one.

Comment: Passing the HttpContext into your domain library is a bad idea.  Also, consuming the IServiceScopeFactory is an anti-pattern.  Please lookup & consider using a IDbContextFactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can create new scope and resolve DbContext there

```
using (var scope = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
using (var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBData>())
{
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to HttpContext in this particular assembly...though maybe I can inject `IServiceScopeFactory`

Comment: Turned out I could. Its not optimal but that seems like a solution